# How can 0.149162536... be normal?

Tags: number-theory

I was reading about [normal numbers on WikiPedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number), and I ran across this statement:

> Besicovitch (1935) proved that the number represented by the same
>   expression, with f(n) = n^2,
>   0.149162536496481100121144..., obtained by concatenating the square numbers in base 10, is normal in base 10.

It seems intuitively that this cannot be true, because the pattern of square numbers taken modulo 10 is `{0, 1, 4, 9, 6, 5, 6, 9, 4, 1}`.  So it seems there will be a higher distribution of those digits throughout the number.  How is it possible this number could have the digits 0-9 equally represented throughout the whole decimal expansion?

Comment: Intuitively, there is almost no information gained from just looking at the last digits of the squares. For any $n > 0$, almost all the squares have at least $n$ digits, and so the bias the last digits give contributes to only $1/n$ of the digits.

Comment: Most digits are not last digits.

Comment: In general, the values of the digits at any subset of density zero is irrelevant. You could change all those last digits to $0$ and it wouldn't matter.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/370774/what-is-the-distribution-of-leading-digits-of-the-squares

Comment: https://oeis.org/A001191

Comment: FYI no one spells Wikipedia as "WikiPedia".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the one's digits become an insignificant fraction of all the digits as we go along.  In the  part from $1^2$ through $99^2$, which is $353$ digits, $99$ of them are from the units place, or better than a quarter.  When $n=10^{100}$ the ones digit contributes only one digit out of $199$ of the square and it keeps decreasing.