# What is the distribution of leading digits of the squares?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, ergodic-theory

Inspired by [How can 0.149162536... be normal?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/370763/how-can-0-149162536-be-normal), I ask for the distribution of the leading coefficients of $1,4,9,16,25,36\ldots$. (namely $1,4,9,1,2,3\ldots$) Does a Benford-like law apply?

The online encyclopedia of integer sequences [has it](http://oeis.org/A002993), and has a tantalizing link to something called [Gelfand's question](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GelfandsQuestion.html).

Comment: It might. The idea of Benford is that the distribution is 'heavy tailed' along the natural numbers so as to be relatively flat in a log-scale graph. I worry that this is not the case for this particular distribution, however, as the growth of the sequence is slow under the $\log$...

Comment: Benford holds on the nose, for instance, for first digits of sequences with a fixed rate of exponential growth, like the powers of $2^n$. The proof invokes the unique ergodicity of irrational rotation on the circle and a clever choice of conjugacy.

Comment: I added the ergodic-theory tag to reflect the connection I mentioned in my last comment.

Comment: Here are the frequencies I got for the first $10^5$ positive integers (from $1$ to $9$): $0.1916$,    $0.1470$,    $0.1239$    $0.1092$,    $0.0987$,    $0.0908$,    $0.0845$,    $0.0793$,    $0.0751$. Note that these do not agree with Benford's law.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Of the $n$ digit numbers, the leading digit of $m^2$ will be $1$ if $\frac m{10^{n-1}}$ is in the range $[1,\sqrt 2]$ or $[\sqrt {10},\sqrt{20}]$.  The first will account for about $(\sqrt 2-1)10^{n-1}$, the second will account for $(\sqrt {20}-\sqrt{10})10^{n-1}$ out of $9\cdot 10^{n-1}$ numbers of that length, so going up to a given number of digits about $0.1916$ of all numbers up to $n$ digits have squares that start with $1$

The values for other leading digits can be computed similarly.  The results are: $$\begin {array}{r | l} \text{leading digit} & \text{fraction}  \\ \hline 1&0.191564\\2&0.146992\\3&0.12392\\4&0.109176\\5&0.098702\\6&0.090766\\7&0.084483\\8&0.079348\\9&0.075049\end{array}$$

These match user17762's result for up to $5$ digit numbers nicely.

Comment: I think you are using $n$ both for the number and the number of digits, which makes it a bit confusing...

Comment: @user17762:  You are right.  Fixed.  Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The leading digit doesn't seem to follow Benford's law. Below is a plot, where the frequency of first digit from the squares of the first $1,000,000$ numbers are plotted.

The Benford law is
$$p(d) \propto \log_{10}\left(1+\dfrac1{d}\right)$$

The empirical law given by $$p(d) \propto \log_{10}\left(1+\dfrac1{\sqrt{d}}\right)$$ seems to be a better fit.

[image]

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline 
\text{Digit} & \text{Benford's law} & \text{Frequency of $1^{st}$ digit of a square} & \text{Emperical law}\\
\hline
1 & 0.3010 & 0.1916 & 0.1867\\
2 & 0.1761 & 0.1470 & 0.1441\\
3 & 0.1249 & 0.1239 & 0.1228\\
4 & 0.0969 & 0.1092 & 0.1092\\
5 & 0.0792 & 0.0987 & 0.0996\\
6 & 0.0669 & 0.0908 & 0.0922\\
7 & 0.0580 & 0.0845 & 0.0864\\
8 & 0.0512 & 0.0793 & 0.0816\\
9 & 0.0458 & 0.0751 & 0.0775\\
\hline
\end{array}

Comment: Your Benford's law does not look right.

Comment: @LordSoth Thanks updated now. I can't imagine how I drew a pdf where one pdf was always above another one =)

Comment: I want to believe your empirical law but the mismatch looks significant, maybe we need to look at the first $10^{10}$ numbers (say). I have also tried the same thing for cubes (with $d^{1/3}$) but that gave an even worse fit.